# Python sorted multidimensional array like day of week

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
a=[["Wed", 27], ["Sun", 90], ["Fri", 69], ["Tue", 47], ["Mon", 54], ["Thu", 40], ["Sat", 78]];
```

I want to sort an array as day of week via python 2.7. Like this;

```
[["Mon", 54], ["Tue", 47], ["Wed", 27], ["Thu", 40], ["Fri", 69], ["Sat", 78], ["Sun", 90]]
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a list with weekday sorted, and then sort list `a` by its key:

```
>>> a = [["Wed", 27], ["Sun", 90], ["Fri", 69], ["Tue", 47], ["Mon", 54], ["Thu", 40], ["Sat", 78]]
>>> order = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: order.index(x[0]))
```

The output will be:

> [['Mon', 54], ['Tue', 47], ['Wed', 27], ['Thu', 40], ['Fri', 69], ['Sat', 78], ['Sun', 90]]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mapping and then sort by that.

```
import operator as op

mapping = {'Mon':0,'Tue':1,'Wed':2,'Thu':3,'Fri':4,'Sat':5,'Sun':6}
orig_list = [["Wed", 27], ["Sun", 90], ["Fri", 69], ["Tue", 47], 
             ["Mon", 54], ["Thu", 40], ["Sat", 78]]
new_list = zip(orig_list,[mapping[i[0]] for i in orig_list])
new_list.sort(key=op.itemgetter(1))
```

Yields:

```
>>> new_list
[(['Mon', 54], 0), (['Tue', 47], 1), (['Wed', 27], 2), (['Thu', 40], 3), 
 (['Fri', 69], 4), (['Sat', 78], 5), (['Sun', 90], 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a **mapping** between your values and numbers, *without using any import*.

```
a = [["Wed", 27], ["Sun", 90], ["Fri", 69], ["Tue", 47], ["Mon", 54], ["Thu", 40], ["Sat", 78]]

mapping = {
  "Mon": 1,
  "Tue": 2,
  "Wed": 3,
  "Thu": 4,
  "Fri": 5,
  "Sat": 6,
  "Sun": 7
}

a.sort(key = lambda x: mapping[x[0]])

print(a)
```

Here you specify that you want to sort your list using an anonymous fonction. This anonymous function will extract the string ("Sun" for example) and take the number corresponding in the mapping.